# What is the name of the cocktail with the greatest number of layers in a layered drink and which order are the various liqueurs poured?

Tags: cocktails, layered-drinks

Could anyone tell me what is the name of the cocktail with largest number of layers in a [layered drink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_drink) and in which order the various liqueurs are poured into it?

> A layered (or "stacked") drink, sometimes called a pousse-café, is a kind of cocktail in which the slightly different densities of various liqueurs are used to create an array of colored layers, typically two to seven. - [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_drink)

Comment: I've seen up to 7 layers of rum in a zombie - alternating lights and darks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most layers I have seen (and drunk) is the Pousse Cafe No. 1 - with 6 layers.

[image]

It has equal measures of 6 liqueurs and spirits:

- Grenadine
- Maraschino
- Creme De Menthe
- Creme De Violette
- Yellow Chartreuse
- Brandy

Pouring uses the usual layer process - pour down the back of a spoon...very gently, so you don't mix with the previous layer.

Pic from [epicurious.com](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/the-pousse-cafe-no-1-51167400)

Comment: A friend of mine mentioned a 7 layer one, but I can't find any reference to it online

Comment: How would you recommend  drinking this?

Comment: Well, although there are some 3 layer drinks that are shooters, to me the art of a layered drink means it should be appreciated. Sip it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - you may be looking for my answer below

Answer (score 3):

Does this count?

> **12-Layer Pousse Café**
>
> - grenadine
> - creme de cassis
> - green creme de menthe
> - maraschino liqueur
> - elderflower liqueur
> - orange curacao
> - benedictine
> - yellow chartreuse
> - green chartreuse
> - fernet branca
> - cognac
> - over-proof rum
>
> [MxMo: Pousse Café](https://theboolion.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/mxmo-pousse-cafe/)

[image]

Here is a [seven-layered Pousse Café](https://craftybartending.com/cocktail-recipes/pousse-cafe/):

[image]

> INGREDIENTS:
>
> - 1/4 shot grenadine
> - 1/4 shot dark crème de cacao
> - 1/4 shot maraschino liqueur
> - 1/4 shot orange curaçao
> - 1/4 shot green crème de menthe
> - 1/4 shot parfait amour
> - 1/2 shot cognac